# What does it mean for a Boolean function to have a single minimal expression as SOP or POS.

Tags: boolean-algebra

My lecturer sometimes asks questions about functions that have a single minimal expression, I have trouble understanding what I can conclude from the fact that the expression is single.
I know that a minimal expression consists of PI, but what does the fact that it is single imply about the K-map?
I would be happy to receive a suggestion regarding a correct way of thinking to solve such problems.
Thanks in advance!

Here are two examples of questions:

1)
Given Boolean function f(x,w,y,z).
It is known that f has a single SOP expression containing exactly 4 products and the total number of literals is 8. What is the best upper bound on the number of input vectors (a,b,c,d) for which f(a,b,c,d) = 0?

2)
Prove or disprove:
Given a K-map of a Boolean function.
If after drawing all the EPIs there is at least one minterm that does not belong to any of the EPIs, then the function has more than a single minimal expression as SOP.
(Of course, two expressions that can be reached from one to the other by The distributive property and associative property are not considered different)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.